# Huge whitespace around plotly chart in bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, plotly, grid-layout

I have a .Net application in which I am trying to create a graph using `bootstrap.js` and `plotly.js`.

I have a problem with a huge white-space in my grid when I create a responsive chart. I have figured out that a part of the problem is that size of the plotly svg-container defaults to 450px in height.

I have created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/equv8d1y/7/) showing the huge white space problem.

In my fiddle I have a small commented code block that sets the layout size, but even setting that doesn't really seem to help with removing most of the white space. Also if it becomes too small it starts cropping away some of the chart.

```
//can adjust size of svg-container
//but doesn't adjust white space
//var layout = {
//  height: 350
//}

//Plotly.plot(gd, pieData, layout);
```

As you might have guessed I would like to make it smaller - remove quite some of the white space, so that the table below doesn't seem so out of place.

Comment: You can go through Plotly.js init configs to set the svg-container height and widht. Use link https://plot.ly/javascript/configuration-options/

Comment: @devutkarsh Thanks! However I don't see an example where they change the svg-container height..

Comment: I have posted the example as answer. Hope that helps. Also please accept the answer if this works. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the layout functionality. For your fiddle example you could do the following:

```
var layout = {
  height: 230,
  width: 100,
  margin: {
    l: 60,
    r: 10,
    b: 0,
    t: 10,
    pad: 4
  }
};

Plotly.plot(gd, pieData, layout);
```

You can play with the margin property values to position your figure properly.

Answer (score 3):

In the layout tag use width and height to set the container.
Use like -

```
var layout = {
    height : 400,
    width : 550,
    title : 'Demo',
    tracetoggle: false
};
```

Also the white space is there because of the modebar (which is to take graph snap, zoom, move etc), so you can replace the modebar as well and then shrink the svg container.

To hide modebar -

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});
```

To shift the graph to top use inline style in the svg-container div element, though this is not the best way but a hack -

```
<div id="myDiv" style="margin-top: -50px;"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the try. However this doesn't suit my needs as I have a responsive web page and I don't know what kind of screen size it being used. I tried removing the modebar in my fiddle, however that doesn't really change much tbh: https://jsfiddle.net/equv8d1y/11/

Comment: @Zeliax - You can use the styling to shift the svg-container, please see my edited answer. Also if there is an overlay problem, you can use z-index. And this is responsive indeed.

Comment: I see. I didn't think it would be. However I found that plotly proved too much of a pain to use so I switched to chart.js. Thanks for trying however :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#allStates{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
```

}

I added this to css and it removed whitespace.

Comment: In the bottom it did. And it killed the pie chart.. There's still quite a lot of white space in the top

Comment: Also if you however of the graph with developer tools open you'd see that there actually is a lot of space taken up by the graph, it does however seem like the table below just "overwrites" that.