# Remove Plotly Whitespace

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, grid, plotly, removing-whitespace

Following the advice here [Huge whitespace around plotly chart in bootstrap grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347339/huge-whitespace-around-plotly-chart-in-bootstrap-grid) to remove whitespace in a plotly display. The example below (shaded blue to show container around graphic) extends well below my display even though I set `b=0` in the margin.

Can this be modified so that the bottom of the graphic is right below the x-axis of this display (in this case, the bottom of the graphic would be right below the `0-` tick mark

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
mode = "gauge+number",
value = 450,
title = {'text': "Speed"},
domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}
))   
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=300,
    height=300,
    margin=dict(l=50,r=50,b=0,t=1),
    paper_bgcolor="LightBlue",
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Add whitepace, bootstrap as tags

Comment: @AkshatZala thanks. That's a bit unfamiliar to me. Do I add that in the code above?